# notation for union of a set and collection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1,A_2,A_3\}$, where $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are sets, and $B$ be a set. I want to express
$$\mathcal{A}?B = \{A_1\cup B,A_2\cup B,A_3\cup B\}. $$

Is there any notation for this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no standard symbol for this. Probably the best way to denote this is using set-builder notation:
$$
\{ A \cup B : A \in \mathcal{A} \}.
$$